# Saving variables in server txt file that users input using php

Tags: php, server, txt

I've got a .txt file on my server, and an input box. Is there any simple way to add the user's input from the input box to the txt file on my server? This might be a bit complicated to answer, but links to good posts / tutorials to point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This sounds a bit like a "xy problem"... So as if you don't really ask how you can solve your task, but how you can solve something you think could solve your task... If so... why not ask the actual question? How you can store data on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function with the `FILE_APPEND` flag.

```
<?php
$filename = './myFile.txt';
$data = $_POST['inputname'] ?? '';
file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

---

Edit: explanation of the line `$data = $_POST['inputname'] ?? '';`

If there is a POST field named `inputname`, it will assign its value to
`$data` variable. If the POST field doesn't exist, it will assign the empty value to the `$data` variable.

Comment: I ran this script with my txt file. When i opened the text file like so: mywebname.com/textfile.txt, it was still blank. Am I doing something wrong? And yes, I changed the directory to be correct.

Comment: @ArturO_O It seems the `$_POST['inputname'] ?? ''` resulted in the empty string due to the null coalescing operator (`??`). Which means you weren't sending `inputname` in the POST data. Best way to simply check that the code works (and you're just sending incorrect POST field` is to set the fallback value to something printable. For example `$data = $_POST['inputname'] ?? 'foo';` should save "foo" to the file.